# editing the dnn:pagingcontrol

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I want to edit the ascx file for the pagingcontrol because it appears like this:

[paging control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n77nh.png)

Notice the "Page 1 of 4" and the "First..." sticks together, and it is really annoying to look at. But when i tried to look for the pagingcontrol file to try to edit it, I cannot find it anywhere.

I read somewhere that there is supposed to be a pagingcontrols file in the controls folder but it is not there for me.

How can i edit the pagingcontrol file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using CsS to style this. Changes to the default controls is a breaking change and would be lost with an upgrade.